# Android App crashing with Error: Resource ID #0x7f0d0061 type #0x12 is not valid

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display DB records using a listView with SimpleCursorAdaptor. The app keeps crashing with the following error: Resource ID #0x7f0d0061 type #0x12 is not valid. 
The crashing Java code is below

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
ListView myList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLocations);


    getListFromDb();
}

public void getListFromDb(){
    Cursor res = myDb.ViewAll();
    startManagingCursor(res);


    //Map cursor from db to viewFields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4, DatabaseHelper.COL_5};
    int[] toViewIDS = new int[]{R.id.viewName, R.id.viewAddress, R.id.viewPostcode, R.id.viewType};

    //Create adaptor to map items from DB to UI
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.item_layout, res, fromFieldNames, toViewIDS, 0);

    // Set adaptor for listView
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

}
```

The two XML files:
activity_view.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewLocations"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

item_layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/viewName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/viewAddress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewName"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/viewPostcode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewAddress"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/viewType"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPostcode"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Why does it keep crashing and what can I do to fix it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The item_layout should be layout not id please change as below:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, res, fromFieldNames, toViewIDS, 0);
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew I think there is nothing wrong with passing the TextView ids (btw the TextView ids are not declared as integer resources) into the the constructor of the SimpleCursorAdapter it is correct according to the Android developer document: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context, int, android.database.Cursor, java.lang.String[], int[], int)